# Where can I read Re:Zero web novel in English from the beginning (vol. 1) until now?

Tags: re-zero

I found out that *Re:Zero* has a public web novel version that is available for free due to [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/33741/)

I did some searching and found the English version. However, I only see it begin from vol. 3 (without vol. 1 or vol. 2).

I would like to know where I can find *Re:Zero Kara Hajimeru Isekai Seikatsu* (web novel) in English, from the beginning (vol 1) until now.

Comment: As far as I can tell, only arc 3 onwards has been translated. Also, given the novel was released for free I have no idea what the situation is regarding licencing of translations. Might be a bit of a legal grey area.

Comment: Take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.