# Which media should I read to continue from where the Re:Zero anime left off?

Tags: re-zero

As most of Re:Zero's audience know the anime ended last week, and since there were a lot of people talking about the important part that was left out "Which I still don't know about", I decided I want to read the light novel to see what happened. Here is the problem, I found out that Re:Zero has a light novel, a web novel, and a manga, so what's the difference between them? Do I read all of them? And where should I start from?

Comment: answer to one of your questions is here: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/33741/are-there-differences-between-the-webnovel-and-lightnovel-versions-of-rezero

Comment: You may want read the wiki [here](http://rezero.wikia.com/wiki/Natsuki_Subaru/Synopsis) arc 3, last 3 paragraph. Warning, major spoiler from LN.

Comment: I can not answer about the difference of each medium but, there is a fan translation group who are doing web novel translation and guide viewers who are coming right after anime. If you like to check that out [here](https://translationchicken.com/2016/09/21/rezero-web-novel-fan-translation-table-of-contents/)

Answer (score 1):

**In short, you should read the light novel from the start.**

*About the reason:* 
I’m currently reading the light novel; actually, the first time Betelgeuse appears is in the 5<sup>th</sup> volume. I’m far from where the anime ended, but the first 5 volumes told many things the anime didn’t. And some of them are really important, in my opinion.

*About the difference:* 
As far I know, the web novel is the original source, and the light novel is a compiled book from that, upon which the manga and anime are based. You said you already watched the whole anime, so I don’t see any reason to read the manga. I don’t know if the web novel has an official translation to English but the light novel does — it’s published in North America by Yen Press. Since it is an official publication you should buy it to support Teppei.

This way you won’t miss anything and support the author. It’s a win-win.